# Get the type of connectivity to a host on android

Tags: android, connectivity

I would like to know the type of connectivity to a host on android. More precisely, for example, I would like to know if the connection established to whatever.com is running through the wifi or the mobile connection.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say wifi will override mobile connectivity and android will route all requests through the wifi interface, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Wifi is turned on it will always be used instead of mobile connectivity. Therefore, you can use Android's `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` method to get the current active network interface. When Android switches between interfaces connections are broken, so a connection to any host can only be made using the active interface.